# Covert Integer to Double in php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am not able to insert a field into Mysql. Input is passed from HTML form as string. I think that problem is due to type mismatch. DB type is double

*And i can't able to convert it into Double or float. using floatval() or Doubleval().*

**usually the input is like 8 i want it convert it as 8.0**

Comment: Show us the query/code you use to insert and the error you get

Answer (score 3):

You can insert `8` perfectly safely into a decimal or float. It doesn't have to be `8.0` at all.

If you are having trouble inserting the value in, it isn't the data type on your database, but another issue.

If you post further detail, we will look into more :)

Edit: Here is some input data into `int`, `decimal` and `float` types:

```
mysql> create table numberTest(inty int(2), decy decimal(3,2), floaty float(3,2));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from numberTest;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into numberTest values(7,7,7);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into numberTest values(7.2,7.2,7.2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from numberTest;
+------+------+--------+
| inty | decy | floaty |
+------+------+--------+
|    7 | 7.00 |   7.00 |
|    7 | 7.20 |   7.20 |
+------+------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

If you can't insert your values, show your insert commands in PHP, it isn't the data type. You are barking up the wrong tree with this question.

Comment: But i have tested it by giving direct values to the table by sql Query using phpMyAdmin. It says error. But if i give 8.0 it inserts..

Comment: @Sivashankar No, really, you *can* insert 8 into a float or decimal data type. See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
        $number = 8;
        echo number_format($number, 1, '.', ' '); //8.0
        echo number_format($number, 2, '.', ' '); //8.00
```